# Prolog kenken solver 4 by 4

Tags: prolog, constraint-programming

so i am trying to solve kenken using prolog but i ran into several problems from the start, first of all lets say i run it like kenken([X1,X2,X3,.....X16]). and i want to solve for this x's with rules i defined before. so lets say the first cell has 3 values X1,X2,and X3 and i want to get 2 by using multiplication meaning that X1*X2*X3=2, now how do i set up a rule to see all posible solutions if i had something like that.
also how would i tell my x's to only use a range of values 1-4.
 i tried to do something like

```
:- use_module(library(clpr)).
solve([X1,X2,X3]):-
    {X1*X2*X3=2}.
```

but its gives me a really weird output.

Answer (score 3):

Since you reason over integers, not floats, consider using `library(clpfd)` instead of CLP(R). In SICStus, SWI and YAP, you can constrain a finite domain variable `X` to the integer range 1-4 with:

`X in 1..4`

You can use the built-in predicate `label/1` to search for concrete solutions. Example with SWI-Prolog:

```
?- Vars = [A,B,C], A*B*C #= 2, Vars ins 1..4, label(Vars).
```

yielding:

```
Vars = [1, 1, 2], A = B, B = 1, C = 2 ;
Vars = [1, 2, 1], A = C, C = 1, B = 2 ;
Vars = [2, 1, 1], A = 2, B = C, C = 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `is` operator to do arithmetic:

`2 is X1*X2*X3`

Note that this will not work unless the X's are all bound to numbers.

Comment: Modern Prolog systems provide *constraints* as a more declarative alternative for `is/2`. OP is already using CLP(R), which does not require `is/2` and also allows variables in arithmetic expressions.